# Indexing numpy arrays with numpy arrays, in arbitrary dimension

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose img is a 2 dimensional numpy array. Suppose also that x and y are integer valued 2 dimensional numpy arrays of the same shape as img. Consider:

```
newImg = img[x, y]
```

newImg is now a 2 dimensional array of the same shape as img where newImg[i,j] == img[ x[i,j], y[i,j] ] for all i and j.

I want to generalize this procedure to an arbitrary number of dimensions. That is, let img be a d-dimensional numpy array and take x[i], for i in range(0, d), to be an integer valued d-dimensional numpy array of the same shape as img. What I basically want is:

```
newImg = img[x[0], x[1], ..., x[d-1]]
```

Which is obviously pseudocode, and not expected to work.

How can I do this with NumPy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried simply

```
newImg = img[x]
```

It looks like this should work!

I'm assuming `x` is a list or tuple of integer arrays satisfying the following conditions

```
len(x) == img.ndim
all(a.shape == img.shape for a in x)
```

which seems to match what you are describing.

Comment: I don't think it's that simple. There's an example below (it was too big to fit in this comment.)

Comment: Oh, wait, I haven't tried x as a tuple of arrays. I'll try that out.

Comment: Sorry, the tuple of arrays works. Note, that is the solution. In my question, I was assuming x was an array of arrays. The tuple works.